# Terniary operator to determine object value

Tags: javascript

I have the following terniary operator :

```
[',' , '|' , ';' , 'TAB'].forEach(separator => separatorSelect.append($('<option>', separator === 'TAB' ? {value: '\t', text: separator} : {value: separator, text: separator})));
```

if separator === tab then the value in the object should be '\t'. It works. But I'm wondering if there's a a way to do the terniary inside the object itself so i wont have to copy the whole object twice.

```
 {value: 'terniary here?', text: separator}
```

Is that possible or is my way the only way it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is:

```
 {
    value: (separator === 'TAB' ? '\t' : separator), 
    text: separator
 }
```

Comment: Thank you , way cleaner